# Dynamic HAProxy configuration

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I try to figure out a way to dynamically manage the loadbalancer configuration.

I want to add and remove "service nodes" depending on the overall system load.

My research so far revealed **"Thalassa"** https://github.com/PearsonEducation/thalassa/blob/master/README.md which uses Node.JS + Seaport to manage clients and then updates the HA-Proxy configuration

Still I am not convinced if Thalassa is stable enough to be used in productive systems. Are there usable alternatives out there which offer the same features ?

Answer (score 4):

If you authorize your stats socket, you can send commands to it.

From the [1.4 documentation](http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt)

> disable server <backend>/<server>
>
> Mark the server DOWN for maintenance. In this mode, no more checks will be
>     performed on the server until it leaves maintenance.
>     If the server is tracked by other servers, those servers will be set to DOWN
>     during the maintenance.
>
> In the statistics page, a server DOWN for maintenance will appear with a
>     "MAINT" status, its tracking servers with the "MAINT(via)" one.
>
> Both the backend and the server may be specified either by their name or by
>     their numeric ID, prefixed with a sharp ('#').
>
> This command is restricted and can only be issued on sockets configured for
>     level "admin".

You can use this to effectively add and remove servers from active service.

Barring that, you can use `option httpchk` and block the check requests on the appserver side when a server should leave or join the balancing group. This requires some means to centrally manage that, of course.

Comment: thx for your idea, thalassa seems to use this node package https://github.com/observing/haproxy, which is in the end using the stats sockets you brought up, since your answer only provides a basic approach to the stats socket, i will still leave the question open, maybe some else knows another high level project like thalassa

Comment: Did you ever find another project? I'm looking to do the same thing